# Height of the middle element in a GWT HeaderPanel

Tags: gwt

I am using a GWT `HeaderPanel`. As a middle element, I am using a `DockLayoutPanel` as follows:

```
<g:DockLayoutPanel width="1200px" height="100%">
    <g:west size="220">
        <g:HTMLPanel styleName="{style.debug}">
            something <br />
            something <br />
        </g:HTMLPanel>
    </g:west>
</g:DockLayoutPanel>
```

The page renders fine but, if the browser window is shrunk vertically, the middle panel goes on top of the footer, which is of course not what you would want with a header panel.

I rather like to have the fixed footer, which is why I am not doing the whole thing using `DockLayoutPanel`. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

EDIT: ok, actually, if the window is grown vertically, the middle panel still does not resize

EDIT2: The HeaderPanel is directly in the root panel and looks like this:

```
<g:HeaderPanel>
    <my.shared:Header></my.shared:Header>
    <my.shared:Middle></my.shared:Middle>
    <my.shared:Footer></my.shared:Footer>
</g:HeaderPanel>
```

Comment: How are you using the `HeaderPanel`? What's its parent widget? (btw, you shouldn't need to size your `DockLayoutPanel`, that's the responsibility of the `HeaderPanel`.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasBroyer I have added (see EDIT2) how my HeaderPanel is done. If I do not size the DockLayoutPanel, it comes out with a height of 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Layout panels 101: `HeaderPanel` is a `RequiresResize` panel, so it must either be put into a `ProvidesResize` panel, such as `RootLayoutPanel`, (or as the middle panel of a `HeaderPanel` [1]) or be given an explicit fixed size.

[1] `HeaderPanel` does not implement `ProvidesResize` because it only fulfills the contract for its middle panel.

Comment: `DockLayourPanel` is a `RequiresResize`. Should it then get resized when it's in the middle panel of a `HeaderPanel`, or should it not because `HeaderPanel` overall does not implement ProvidesResize?

Comment: `HeaderPanel` does provide the _resize_ for its middle panel, that's the crux of the widget. The only reason `HeaderPanel` is not a `ProvidesResize` is because it doesn't fulfill the contract for the header and footer widgets (quite obviously)

Comment: Understood. But then what I'm trying to do *should* work, right?

Comment: Provided `HeaderPanel` itself is given its size. `RootPanel` won't do that. You need a `RootLayoutPanel` or `ResizePanel`.

Comment: So that was it. HeaderPanel also needed a size. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

The following approach worked for me.  It's based on Zack Linder's advice 
[Google Web Toolkit ›layout panel problem](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/Fx6uZyaQxDA)

(1) Attach a HeaderLayoutPanel to your RootLayoutPanel.  The headerLayoutPanel is a class you create that extends HeaderPanel and implements ProvidesResize().

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HeaderPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ProvidesResize;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.SimpleLayoutPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;

public class HeaderLayoutPanel extends HeaderPanel implements ProvidesResize {
SimpleLayoutPanel contentPanel;

public HeaderLayoutPanel() {
    super();
    contentPanel=new SimpleLayoutPanel();
}

    @Override
    public void setContentWidget(Widget w) {
       contentPanel.setSize("100%","100%");
       contentPanel.setWidget(w);
       super.setContentWidget(contentPanel);
    }

    public void onResize() {
      int w=Window.getClientWidth();
      int h=Window.getClientHeight();
      super.setPixelSize(w, h);
    }
}
```

(2) Next, instantiate a HeaderLayoutPanel.  The header and footer widgets are assigned
a fixed height (e.g. menu bar height), and their width adjusts automatically to the
width of the panel.  The center widget should be a ProvidesSize.  I used a LayoutPanel.
For example,

```
 public class AppViewer extends Composite implements MyApp.AppDisplay {

private HeaderLayoutPanel allContentsPanel;
MenuBar menuBarTop;
MenuBar menuBarBottom;
LayoutPanel dataPanel;

public AppViewer() {

    allContentsPanel = new HeaderLayoutPanel(); 
    menuBarTop = new MenuBar(false);
    menuBarBottom = new MenuBar(false);
    dataPanel = new LayoutPanel();

    menuBarTop.setHeight("30px");
    menuBarBottom.setHeight("20px");

    allContentsPanel.setHeaderWidget(menuBarTop);       
    allContentsPanel.setFooterWidget(menuBarBottom);                            
    allContentsPanel.setContentWidget(dataPanel);

    initWidget(allContentsPanel);
}


@Override
public void doOnResize() {
    allContentsPanel.onResize();
}   
  }
```

(3) The center widget (LayoutPanel) will hold the DeckLayoutPanel, which I defines in a
separate Composite (but you can do whatever you want).  For example,

```
    public class MyDataView extends Composite implements MyDataPresenter.DataDisplay {      
        private DockLayoutPanel pnlAllContents;
    private HorizontalPanel hpnlButtons;
    private HorizontalPanel hpnlToolbar;
    private VerticalPanel pnlContent;

    public MyView() {
    pnlAllContents=new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.PX);
    pnlAllContents.setSize("100%", "100%"); 
    initWidget(pnlAllContents);

    hpnlToolbar = new HorizontalPanel();
    hpnlToolbar.setWidth("100%");   
    pnlAllContents.addNorth(hpnlToolbar, 30);

    hpnlButtons = new HorizontalPanel();
    hpnlButtons.setWidth("100%");
    pnlAllContents.addSouth(hpnlButtons,20);

    pnlContent=new VerticalPanel(); 
    //center widget - takes up the remainder of the space
    pnlAllContents.add(pnlContent);

    ...
         }
}
```

(4) Finally everything gets tied together in the onModuleLoad() class: AppViewer generates
the display which is added to the RootLayoutPanel, and MyDataView generates a display.asWidget()
that is added to the container.  For example,

```
public class MyApp implements EntryPoint,Presenter{

  private HasWidgets container=RootLayoutPanel.get();
  private static AppDisplay display;  
  private DataPresenter dataPresenter;

    public interface AppDisplay extends Display{
        @Override
        Widget asWidget();
        HasWidgets getContentContainer();
        void doOnResize();
        }

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        display=new AppViewer();
        dataPresenter = new DataPresenter();
        display.getContentContainer().add(dataPresenter.getDisplay().asWidget());
        container.add(display.asWidget());
        bind();
        }

       @Override
       public void bind() {

    Window.addResizeHandler(new ResizeHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onResize(ResizeEvent event) {
            display.doOnResize();
        }
    });
        }


       @Override
       public com.midasmed.client.presenter.Display getDisplay() {
        return display;
       }
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I haven't been able to solve this but, for future visitors: the same can be achieved (minus the problem I couldn't fix) using a `DockLayourPanel` with a north, center and south components.